# jQuery calculate field from two other fields

Tags: jquery

I don't get it why is this not working properly:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze5tsgy9/1/)

I just want to show the tax amount but it gets `false` results.

```
// calculate brutto and tax
$(document).on('keyup paste', '#netto', function() {
    var brutto = $("#brutto").val();
    var netto = $("#netto").val();
    $("#brutto").val(netto * 1.19);
    $("#tax").val(brutto - netto);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you get the brutto value before filling it, the solution is to get `var brutto` after you calculate `$("#brutto").val(netto * 1.19)`:

```js
// calculate brutto and tax
$(document).on('keyup paste', '#netto', function() {
    var netto = +$("#netto").val();
    $("#brutto").val(netto * 1.19);
    var brutto = +$("#brutto").val();
    $("#tax").val(brutto - netto);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="brutto">Brutto</label>
    <input class="form-control" readonly="readonly" name="brutto" type="text" id="brutto">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="tax">Taxes 19%</label>
    <input class="form-control" readonly="readonly" name="tax" type="text" id="tax">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="netto">Netto</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="netto" type="text" id="netto">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try following code :

```
// calculate brutto and tax
$(document).on('keyup paste', '#netto', function () {

    var brutto = $("#brutto").val();
    var netto = $("#netto").val();

    $("#brutto").val(netto * 1.19);

    var brutto1 = $("#brutto").val();   

    $("#tax").val(brutto1 - netto);
```

});

In your code the value of brutto is not updated in variable after new value (natto * 1.19), so you gets false result.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate the value of `brutto` element is a number before performing operation. the `+` operator is use to convert input to a number.

```
$(document).on('keyup paste', '#netto', function() {
    var brutto = +$("#brutto").val() || 1;
    var netto = +$("#netto").val() || 1;
    brutto = netto * 1.19;
    $("#brutto").val(brutto);
    $("#tax").val(brutto - netto);
});
```

This will also be useful since the element is readonly.
[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ze5tsgy9/5/)

Comment: can you define valid? how do you mean? Why is this not working? what happens behind the scenes, can you describe?

Comment: @lewis4u, As you are performing mathematical operation you need to check the input is a number or not

Comment: OK...is there maybe some function in jQuery to check if isset() like in php

Comment: @lewis4u, you can check through js typeof method, if number is in string "8" you can change it to type number by +"8".

Comment: @lewis4u, Next time please english term, as I am totally unaware of term `brutto`

Answer (score 1):

Parse you strings to int, change the event to a input type event:

```
 $(document).on('input', '#netto', function () {

  var brutto = parseInt($("#brutto").val());
  var netto = parseInt($("#netto").val());

  $("#brutto").val(netto * 1.19);
  $("#tax").val((netto * 1.19) - netto );


});
```

better if you go with a input type number so you don't have problems with invalid values

https://jsfiddle.net/ze5tsgy9/6/
or:

https://jsfiddle.net/ze5tsgy9/7/ if you want to get rid of NaN when its empty

Comment: Don't forget `radix` with `parseInt()`

Comment: what is radix??

Comment: @lewis4u, base of mathematical number see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Yes it works. but it is not optimal. user Francesco Roggia has made the point why my code didn't work. The key part is that I was declaring brutto at the beginning instead of after the brutto was calculated...i just needed to switch the lines and it works now!